# Boost serialization only works in main? Keep saying "has no member named ‘serialize’" when I use in other objects

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, boost

I am currently using c++ boost library to save some data from a real time control system (OS: Linux). The data I want is save is a object define in the following way:

```
#ifndef RECDATA_HPP
#define RECDATA_HPP
#include <vector>
template<class T>
class RecData
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> data;
    std::vector<unsigned long> time;
    // Allow serialization to access non-public data members.
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    // Implement serialize method
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & data;
        ar & time;
    } 


public:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> getData(){
        return this->data;
    }
    std::vector<unsigned long> getTime(){
        return this->time;
    }
    void PushData(std::vector<T> inData);
    void PushTime(unsigned long curTime);
};
template<class T>
void RecData<T>::PushData(std::vector<T> inData){
    this->data.push_back(inData);
}
template<class T>
void RecData<T>::PushTime(unsigned long curTime){
    this->time.push_back(curTime);
}

#endif //RECDATA_HPP
```

This works fine when I directly save it in main, for example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

#include "vect_container.hpp"
#include "Recorder.hpp"
#include "RecData.hpp"


int main()
{
    RecData<int> *recData1 = new RecData<int>();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        std::vector<int> temp;
        for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
            temp.push_back(i+k);
        }
        recData1->PushData(temp);
        recData1->PushTime((unsigned long)i);
    }
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("temp.dat");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);
        ar & *recData1;
        delete recData1;
    }

    RecData<int> restore = RecData<int>();
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("temp.dat");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ar(ifs);
        ar &restore;
    }

    std::vector<unsigned long> timeGet = restore.getTime();
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> dataGet = restore.getData();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        std::cout<<timeGet[i]<<std::endl;
        for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
            std::cout<<dataGet[i][k];
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }   
}
```

However, if now I call this method in an object, it cannot compile.

```cpp
template<class T>
void Recorder::writeTemp(RecData<T> *tempData, int recType)
{
    {
        std::ofstream ofs(this->fileName);
        boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);
        ar & *tempData;
        delete tempData;
    }
}
```

The compiler kept telling me:

```
 error: ‘class std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >’ has no member named ‘serialize’
```

or

```
 error: ‘class std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >’ has no member named ‘serialize’
```

Yet, I believe I have clearly defined serialize in class RecData, and it worked when I serialize such object in main. I wonder what is the reason of this problem.

Comment: "Boost serialization only works in main?" - No. Obviously not. That would be close to meaningless.

Comment: I totally agree, but I really cannot understand why same object cannot be serialized in object, I tried to print the value in the object, it returned me correct value, all errors occurs at ar & *tempData line....

Comment: Can it be that your main is including via, for example "vector_container.hpp" the file boost/serialization/vector.hpp while the file where you define your function is not? Sorry but without  a minimal reproducible example I cannot be sure, hence posting as comment. And also my MSVC seems to have issue with linking with Boost, so I cannot test.

Comment: The comment above is undoubtedly correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I edited your snipped in order to produce the following minimum reproducible example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
//Comment below line, get same error
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

template<class T>
class RecData
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> data;
    std::vector<unsigned long> time;
    // Allow serialization to access non-public data members.
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    // Implement serialize method
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar& data;
        ar& time;
    }

public:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> getData() {
        return this->data;
    }
    std::vector<unsigned long> getTime() {
        return this->time;
    }
    void PushData(std::vector<T> inData);
    void PushTime(unsigned long curTime);
};


template<class T>
void RecData<T>::PushData(std::vector<T> inData) {
    this->data.push_back(inData);
}
template<class T>
void RecData<T>::PushTime(unsigned long curTime) {
    this->time.push_back(curTime);
}



int main()
{
    RecData<int>* recData1 = new RecData<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::vector<int> temp;
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            temp.push_back(i + k);
        }
        recData1->PushData(temp);
        recData1->PushTime((unsigned long)i);
    }
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("temp.dat");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);
        ar&* recData1;
        delete recData1;
    }
}
```

If I comment out

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
```

I get the same errors you are getting,

```
Error   C2039    'serialize': is not a member of 'std::vector<std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allo>cator<_Ty>>>>' 
Error   C2039    'serialize': is not a member of 'std::vector<unsigned long,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
```

If I keep the line it compiles.
I therefore believe that in some way, your main is including indirectly the aforementioned header, while the file where you define your function is not.
Try to include the header also in the file where your function is defined on in the header where you define `RecData`. I would argue that it should go in the header of `RecData` given that the file is needed to successfully use the class, but the choice is up to you.

Tested in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, Boost 1.70.0